# Creating array as input in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

In excel I am using the index() function as an array function as follows:

```
   =index(array, row, {1,2})
```

where array = the range which from which the "row" and {column 1, column 2} is returned.

If I want to return few columns I can explicitly write down the columns as I am doing above. i.e. to return column 1 and 2 I am passing {1,2} as the third argument of index().

But say I want to return column 17 through 47, what is the way to give an input something like "{17:47}" or say if I want to give  {n1 through n2} and then {n3 through n4} where n1, n2,n3,n4 are numbers. e.g. {5,11} and {17:21}.

Is there a way to give this type of inputs without explicitly writing down the columns numbers.

Comment: For contiguous numbers you can use the ROW() function; `ROW(14:47)`

Comment: are these other locations always the same, or do they vary?

Is there some predictability to them, ie can they be identified with a formula yield them?